# Java GUI wont show JLabel from input

Tags: java

I would like to create a simple Blackjack GUI in Java. I know the basics of creating JLabel, JPanel etc. However, I cannot find why my JLabel is not displayed on the screen. Here is my code:

```
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BlackJack");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //new border panel
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));

        //create players panel
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        panel2.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        gui.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("BlackJack!");


        //add players name
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name?");
        JLabel playerName = new JLabel(name);
        playerName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
        playerName.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.BOLD, 18));
        panel2.add(playerName);
```

When I hit compile, what I get is a dialog for name? and then an empty panel. I do not understand why my JLabel is not in the panel since I have added it to my frame. Am I missing something?

Comment: And `IO` is... what? (And what the answers say about the logical expression.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(nloop != 1 || nloop != 2){
```

This is a [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28logic%29).

For each number - it cannot be both 1 and 2 - so the condition `(nloop != 1 || nloop != 2)` always yields `true`.

Maybe you wanted `&&` instead of `||`?

---

The while loop: `while(run2 = true){` also [smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), as pointed in comments (though it doesn't seem to be the issue stated in the question).

Comment: And `while(run2 = true)` is better written as `while(true)`, so as not to confuse others that you mistyped `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: @RohitJain: Thanks, added indication for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
if(nloop != 1 || nloop != 2){
```

to

```
if(nloop != 1 && nloop != 2){
```

Think about it. If you enter 1, your original if condition checks if 1 is unequal to 1 OR 1 is unequal to 2. 1 is obviously != 2, so the bad input code is executed.

Instead, you want your bad input code to run only if the input is not 1 AND not 2.